# Testing Membership provider without ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, membership-provider

I have a ASP.NET MVC site using Membership Provider.  I have trouble testing some functionalities including register a new user.

The ASP.NET website doesn't have a way to delete/remove a registered user, so in my testing project (WatiN with NUnit), I am trying to delete a testing user account by calling Membership.DeleteUser(). Then I realize I cannot use this since I cannot configure the membership provider with web.config in my NUnit project (in visual studio).

How do I configure the membership provider without using ASP.NET?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You configure it in your app.config for your NUnit project.  Check out [this blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20190907171551/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/AzamSharp/archive/2007/12/30/118071.aspx).  It provides an example (or close) to what you want to do.

Add the following to your app.config (from the first blog above):

> ```
>  <system.web>
>
>     <membership defaultProvider="MeanWormMembershipProvider">
>       <providers>
>         <remove name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"/>
>         
>           <add applicationName="MeanWorm" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
>             requiresUniqueEmail="true" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
>             enablePasswordReset="true" passwordFormat="Hashed" connectionStringName="MeanWormConnectionString"
>             name="MeanWormMembershipProvider" type="MeanWorm.Domain.Providers.MeanWormMembershipProvider,MeanWorm.Domain"/>
>         
>       </providers>
>     </membership>
>   </system.web>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into the [Client Application Services](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/ClientApplicationServices.aspx)? I'm not sure if that is what you want, but it is worth looking into.